# Trouble with Navtab

Tags: html, css

I´m learning HTML and CSS from the freecodecamp. With all the Bootstrap code I'm a bit confused.

Here is my code:

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  color: coral;
  font-family: verdana;
}
ul {                
  height: 20%;
  background-color: darkgrey;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: solid;                                              
}
li {   
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0% 5% 0% 5%;
  text-align:                    
}
#first {
  margin: 0% 0% 0% 30%;
}
li:hover {           
  background-color: bisque;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<h1> Test Website </h1>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="menu">
    <div id="tope"></div>
    <ul id="navbar">                   
      <li id="first"><a href="www.a.com"> Us </a></li>
      <li><a href="www.b.com"> Work </a></li>
      <li id="last"><a href="www.c.com"> Vids and photos </a></li>   
    </ul>    
  </div>
</div>
```

Demo: [CodePen](http://codepen.io/cetaphil/pen/YWjpYR).

The problem that I am struggling on is that my navtab (actually, all the `<li>` elements) don't follow the main title `<h1>` element when I resize the screen.

I want to make some kind of grid system, where my `<li>` are centered in relation to the `<h1>`, but without Bootstrap. Is that possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your list is not aligning properly on resize is that you have added a `margin-right` value to `#first`.  That shifts everything out of alignment.  But you are **very close** to achieving your desired results!

You just need to make a few corrections:

http://www.bootply.com/YHHS5on2Ej

```
ul {                
    background-color: darkgrey;
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

li {   
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0% 5% 0% 5%;
}
```

Get rid of all the CSS for `#first` and note that `display:solid` is not valid CSS

Answer (score 0):

Try sth like this for `.menu`, `ul` and `li`.
I dont know if this fits your needs, but with this code you set a width for your `ul` and then `margin: auto` centers it and is kept down the header.

```
        .menu {
           background: darkgrey;
        }


        ul {                
            height: 20%;
            list-style-type: none;
            width: 300px; 
            margin: auto
        }

        li {   
            display: inline-block;
            padding: 0% 5% 0% 5%;

        }
```